# Setting up output paths in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am going to have a fairly large solution, with many projects in it, and there are reasons while I my folders with source code in it must have no .obj or .exe or .dll files at any point. So, I came up with this structure:

```
SolutionDirectory
 |- MainProject
     |- MainProject.csproj
     |- Main.cs
     ...
 |- FirstSlaveProject
     |- FirstSlaveProject.csproj
     ...
 |- SecondSlaveProject
     |- SecondSlaveProject.csproj
 ...
 |- BuildFolder
     |- MainProject
         |- bin
         |- obj
     |- FirstSlaveProject
         |- bin
         |- obj
     |- SecondSlaveProject
         |- bin
         |- obj
     ...
```

The idea is that all source files are inside projects' folders, and all binaries go to "BuildFolder", sorted by project's name. Seems pretty reasonable, right?

So, I reckon when I create a new project inside my solution, I have to write somewhere something like this: `%SolutionFolder%\BuildFolder\%ProjectName%\%ProjectConfigName%\bin" and "%SolutionFolder%\BuildFolder\%ProjectName%\%ProjectConfigName%\obj`.

So, where exactly do I write this (and I hope I don't have to write it for each Debug, Release, UnstableSpeedup, etc. configuration separately!), and how exactly? I doubt Visual Studio will recognize `%SolutionFolder`.

Is there maybe some sort of a shell script, or a Visual Studio addin, or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open the .csproj file and insert this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)BuildFolder\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(Configuration)-$(Platform)\bin\</OutputPath>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)BuildFolder\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(Configuration)-$(Platform)\obj\</IntermediateOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

after the **last** `PropertyGroup` tag.

I tested it, and the EXE file indeed appeared inside `"SolutionDirectory\BuildFolder\MainProject\Debug-x86\bin"`, and all intermediate stuff went to `"SolutionDirectory\BuildFolder\MainProject\Debug-x86\obj"`. Visual Studio still creates an empty "obj" directory inside my source tree though... whatever, since it's empty, it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Once the project is created, right click on the project, then click *Properties*. On the build tab is a box for the output path.

I don't know if there is a way to automate it for each project.

Comment: Sadly, it a) doesn't move "obj" directory, b) works per configuration. Setting up 6 different paths manually (Debug-x86, Debug-x64, Release-x86, Release-x64, UnstableSpeedup-x86, UnstableSpeedup-x64) is annoying. And what exactly do I write into the "Output" box?

Comment: The output path is the directory you want the binaries to be output to. In your case it would be ..\BuildFolder\MainProject, ..\BuildFolder\FirstSlaveProject, etc.  You shouldn't have to manually create folders for each build.  And if the folder doesn't exist in the directory, it will create it when you go to build.

Comment: I missed the configuration dropdown at the top.  You could also unload the project and edit the .csproj directly, so you didn't have to switch the configuration drop down.